# How to get number of rows using SqlDataReader in C#

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

My question is how to get the number of rows returned by a query using `SqlDataReader` in C#. I've seen some answers about this but none were clearly defined except for one that states to do a while loop with `Read()` method and increment a counter.

My problem is that I am trying to fill a multi-dimensional array with the first row being the column header names and every row after that to the be the row data.

I know that I can just dump the stuff in a List control and not worry about it, but for my own personal edification and I would also like to pull the data in and out of the array as I choose and display it in different formats.

So I think I can't do the `Read()` and then increment ++ way because that means that I would have to open `Read()` and then open `Read()` again to get amount of rows and then column data.

Just a small example of what I'm talking about:

```
int counter = 0;    

while (sqlRead.Read())
{
    //get rows
    counter++
}
```

and then a for loop to run through the columns and pop

```
something.Read();

int dbFields = sqlRead.FieldCount;

for (int i = 0; i < dbFields; i++)
{
   // do stuff to array
}
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

There are only two options:

- Find out by reading all rows (and then you might as well store them)
- run a specialized SELECT COUNT(*) query beforehand.

Going twice through the DataReader loop is really expensive, you would have to re-execute the query.

And (thanks to Pete OHanlon) the second option is only concurrency-safe when you use a transaction with a Snapshot isolation level.

Since you want to end up storing all rows in memory anyway the only sensible option is to read all rows in a flexible storage (`List<>` or `DataTable`) and then copy the data to any format you want. The in-memory operation will always be much more efficient.

Comment: Henk is right: there is no member of the DataReader that allows you to get the number of rows because it is a forward only reader. You are better off first doing getting the count and then executing the query, perhaps in a multi-result query so you only hit the database once.

Comment: The problem with the specialized count is that there's the potential for the count being different from the number of returned rows because somebody else has changed the data in a way that leads to the number of rows being returned.

Comment: Pete, you are right, it would require an expensive IsolationLevel.

Comment: Thank you all! This is becoming more clear. So is it better to dump all the info to the DataSet or run through a SQL COUNT(*), store it and then run the required query? Or are we talking about running count and storing everything in the DataSet?

Comment: A DataSet would solve all thos problems at once, if you find it a usable format. It is quite capable. The other approach would be DataReader + List<>

Comment: You can use DataSet or objects in memory if you are not dealing with many many rows. Or you'll increase a lot your memory usage.

Comment: The only problem with using a DataSet is the amount of memory required to store all the results in memory at once.  A DataSet actually makes this problem worse because it adds a lot of bloat with all of it's relationships.

That said, if you decide that is the best option, you should look at using a DataAdapter instead of a DataReader, since it's built to do all the footwork of filling a DataSet for you.

Comment: A `RepeatableRead` isolation level does not perform range-locking so it still allows records to be inserted, you need to be using an isolation level of `Snapshot` or `Serializable`.

Answer (score 10):

If you do not need to retrieve all the row and want to avoid to make a double query, you can probably try something like that:

```
using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Database=MyDb;User Id=Me;Password=glop;"))
      {
        sqlCon.Open();

        var com = sqlCon.CreateCommand();
        com.CommandText = "select * from BigTable";
        using (var reader = com.ExecuteReader())
        {
            //here you retrieve what you need
        }

        com.CommandText = "select @@ROWCOUNT";
        var totalRow = com.ExecuteScalar();

        sqlCon.Close();
      }
```

You may have to add a transaction not sure if reusing the same command will automatically add a transaction on it...

Comment: Anyone can say if @@ROWCOUNT always rely on the last query that runs above? Problems if many connections runs queries parallel?

Comment: Is it needed to do `sqlCon.Close();`? I thought that `using` should do it for you.

Comment: it will not work in case when we need rowcount before retrieving data from reader

Answer (score 8):

As others have said, a dataset or typed dataset might be a good temporary structure which you could use to do your filtering. A SqlDataReader is meant to read the data very quickly. While you are in the while() loop you are still connected to the DB and it is waiting for you to do whatever you are doing in order to read/process the next result before it moves on. In this case you might get better performance if you pull in all of the data, close the connection to the DB and process the results "offline".

People seem to hate datasets, so the above could be done with a collection of strongly typed objects as well.

Comment: I love DataSets myself, since they're a well-written and extremely useful generic representation of table-based data. Weirdly enough, I've noticed that most people who eschew the DataSet for ORM are the same people who try to write their own code to be as generic as possible (usually pointlessly).

Answer (score 7):

You can't get a count of rows directly from a data reader because it's what is known as a firehose cursor - which means that the data is read on a row by row basis based on the read being performed. I'd advise against doing 2 reads on the data because there's the potential that the data has changed between doing the 2 reads, and thus you'd get different results.

What you could do is read the data into a temporary structure, and use that in place of the second read. Alternatively, you'll need to change the mechanism by which you retrieve the data and use something like a DataTable instead.

Answer (score 7):

to complete of Pit answer and for better perfromance :
get all in one query and use NextResult method.

```
using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Database=MyDb;User Id=Me;Password=glop;"))
{
    sqlCon.Open();
    var com = sqlCon.CreateCommand();
    com.CommandText = "select * from BigTable;select @@ROWCOUNT;";
    using (var reader = com.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(reader.Read()){
            //iterate code
        }
        int totalRow = 0 ;
        reader.NextResult();
        if(reader.Read()){
            totalRow = (int)reader[0];
        }
    }
    sqlCon.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also face a situation when I needed to return a top result but also wanted to get the total rows that where matching the query. i finaly get to this solution:

```
   public string Format(SelectQuery selectQuery)
    {
      string result;

      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectQuery.WherePart))
      {
        result = string.Format(
@"
declare @maxResult  int;
set @maxResult = {0};

WITH Total AS
(
SELECT count(*) as [Count] FROM {2}
)
SELECT top (@maxResult) Total.[Count], {1} FROM Total, {2}", m_limit.To, selectQuery.SelectPart, selectQuery.FromPart);
      }
      else
      {
        result = string.Format(
@"
declare @maxResult  int;
set @maxResult = {0};

WITH Total AS
(
SELECT count(*) as [Count] FROM {2} WHERE {3}
)
SELECT top (@maxResult) Total.[Count], {1} FROM Total, {2} WHERE {3}", m_limit.To, selectQuery.SelectPart, selectQuery.FromPart, selectQuery.WherePart);
      }

      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectQuery.OrderPart))
        result = string.Format("{0} ORDER BY {1}", result, selectQuery.OrderPart);

      return result;
    }
```