# IDataReader - Any way to get the total rows?

Tags: c#, count, rows, datareader

Is there any way to get the total number of rows returned from a SQL query (from the IDataReader) before iterating through the rows by using `reader.Read();`?

Comment: @sll: The reference you point to is no longer valid, go figure.

Comment: Updated link, See [how to get number of rows using SqlDataReader in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1383315/485076)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.

`IDataReader` is a simple forward-only view of a resultset; it cannot get a count.

Answer (score 6):

No, the datareader will not return a count first.  However, if you do need to do it, use two queries that return multiple result sets.

for example in SQL Server:

```
sql = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM A; SELECT * FROM A;"
```

Iterate the result sets.  Use the `IDataReader` on the second result set.

The database server should be able to do this quite fast if it is using appropriate indexes.

Comment: Something like this fails in the general case, e.g. `EXECUTE ReportQuestionsWithMoreThanTenAnswersAndNoAccepted`

Answer (score 4):

Well past the date posted but there is a way, that worked for me took a while to get because i suck at wording my google searches.

```
dbCommand.Connection.Open();
//dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();  I left this here to show not to do the read

searchCount = dbCommand.ExecuteScalar(); // this line returns the value count
                                         // from my tests on my reader it works perfectly
```

Comment: Wouldn't this require two separate executions, meaning that it could be vulnerable to a race condition if someone changes something between calling ExecuteScalar() (to get the count) and calling ExecuteReader() (to get the rows themselves)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not an good idea, but i got count using variable inside while loop. This code work fine for me:

```
IDataReader reader = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(sqlConnectionString, Procedure.GetSuperUserOwnerDetails, ProfileName);
int count = 0;
while (reader.Read())
{
   count = count + 1;
}
lblProfileOperator.Text = " Owner : " + count;
```

Answer (score -1):

The count of rows calculated only when you read the DataReader
but i didnt get it , why you want to know the rows count before reading it.

Comment: To allocate exactly the perfect amount of storage necessary if storing a copy of the whole result set (instead of, for example, letting [List(T).Add()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1) automatically grow its [Capacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2) often).

Comment: That's the most obvious one I had in mind too.  Another use case would be to update a determinate progress bar while reading rows.  Another MIGHT be as input into a heuristic for how to process the rows (i.e., you may want to process 100 rows differently from how you would process 10 million rows, and it might be a pain to switch partway through).  Probably tons of other legitimate reasons, too.

Comment: To create a progress bar during an export. To provide user feedback.