# How to get how many element datareader has read?

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, sqldatareader

How to get the length of a datareader, something like:

```
sqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
dr.Read();

int L= dr.Length;// this doesn't work.
```

?

Comment: Number of rows or columns?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383315/how-to-get-number-of-rows-using-sqldatareader-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can keep track of how many items you've *already* read from the `DataReader` simply by using a counter. However, I don't believe there's any general way of finding out how many rows there *will* be without just reading them:

```
int count = 0;
while (dr.Read())
{
    // Use the row data, presumably
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Datareader provides a Count property on itself. You would need whether to loop the datareader and increment a variable OR perform first a select count(*) with the same conditions you use in your command execution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *direct* method (At least I don't know) to count the rows or columns. Use a custom counter in your `while` loop.

- Find out by reading all rows as a custom operation. Like;

---

```
while(dr.Read())
{
     // Do your operations..
     counter++;
}
```

- Run a query like `Select Count(*)` before your operation.