# How to handle multiple rows scenario in SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have a `SQL` query which `supposed` to return only `ONE` row from the business database. Based on this, I have written following `sql script` to get the data from the result set.

```
string query = @"select 
ProdMaster.data_Id Id,
ProdMaster.data_name Name,
ProdMaster.data_countryname CountryName
from RM.Db
order by ProdMaster.data.FromDate desc"

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
 if (reader.Read()) 
   {                            
      countryname = reader["CountryName"].ToString(); 
   }
}
```

But, there is some data issue in the database, sometimes it returns multiple rows.

How do we check the row `count`? If rows more than one we want to return a custom exception.

**Note**:

- I do not want to use COUNT(*) in the query.
- We don't have control on `RM.Db` database - it might have data issues (3rd party)

Comment: It depends on what you have in your `command`. Can you show that?

Comment: updated the query

Comment: Do you want to know exact number of rows returned or just want to throw an exception if number of rows is more than 1?

Comment: @IliarTurdushev  Yes, if only ONE row, then I want to read  the value.

Comment: If you changed `if` to `while` then you could keep track of the row count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you consider the next approach to solve your problem:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.Read()) 
    {                            
        countryname = reader["CountryName"].ToString(); 
    }

    // Try to read the second row.
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        // If we are inside this if-statement then it means that the query has returned more than one row.
        // Here a custom exception must be thrown.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SqlDataAdapter` instead and fill the contents from the table in a dataset. The dataset will have a table inside it you can count the row like this - `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count`

There can be problems related to Datareader as it is a stream of data and db can have changes while reading. A more thorough discussion on the same can be found on this thread - 
[How to get number of rows using SqlDataReader in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383315/how-to-get-number-of-rows-using-sqldatareader-in-c-sharp)